# Log severity levels are always any on google standard app engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, logging

log severity levels always show any on the google standard app engine. Here is snippet I am using.

```
import google.cloud.logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler

client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client)
handler.setFormatter(CustomFormatter())
google.cloud.logging.handlers.setup_logging(handler)
logging.getLogger("name").setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is known and it looks there’s already a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/126702594) , it seems it comes from an internal limitation. I’ve found this comment related to the logging in GAE:
Bubbling up the application log severity in the request logs is not feasible in App Engine second generation.